# Complex interpolation of weighted $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, interpolation-theory

Bergh and Löfstrom's book *Interpolation spaces - An introduction* gives a short proof sketch (Thm. 5.5.3, p. 120) of the fact that the complex interpolation space $(L^{p_0}(w_0), L^{p_1}(w_1))_{[θ]}$ is $L^{p_θ}({w_0}^{(1-θ) p_θ/p_0} {w_1}^{θ p_θ/p_1})$. Here
$\frac{1}{p_\theta} = \frac{1-\theta}{p_0} + \frac{\theta}{p_1}$

The proof consists of the claim that the map $\mathcal{F}\left(L^{p_0}(w_0), L^{p_1}(w_1)\right)  \to \mathcal{F}(L^{p_0}, L^{p_1}), f \mapsto \tilde{f}$ defined by
$$
 \tilde{f}(z) = f(z) \cdot {w_0}^{(1-z)/p_0} {w_1}^{z/p_1}
 \tag{1}
$$
is an isometric isomorphism between the spaces.
Here $\mathcal{F}(X, Y)$ denotes the space of continuous bounded functions from the strip $0 ≤ \operatorname{Re} z ≤ 1$ into $X + Y$ that are holomorphic in the interior and whose norm along the boundary tend to zero at infinity, from which the interpolation space is constructed.

Deducing the theorem from this claim seems straightforward, but I see two problems with the claim itself:

- First, I don't see why the RHS of (1), for a particular value of $z$, is a function in $L^{p_0} + L^{p_1}$. In the case $p_0 = p_1$ this basically already is the whole claim of the interpolation result.
  And in general, $g \in L^p(w_0) + L^p(w_1)$ does not imply $g \in L^p({w_0}^{1-θ} {w_1}^θ)$.
- Second, I don't see how you can conclude that this is surjective. In fact, if $w_0$ or $w_1$ are zero somewhere this seems to be false.

Any pointers on this?

The isometry of the tilde map on the other hand is immediate from the definition of the norm on the $\mathcal{F}$-spaces.

Comment: What are the assumptions on the weights?

Comment: The weights are usually positive. Surjectivity follows from the fact that you can indicate the inverse mapping.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sorry, I meant to say that there's a problem if the weights are zero somewhere. Are you saying that the result is only true for positive weights?

Comment: I do not see the surjectivity. For example if we are considering $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and the weights $w_0=\chi_{(-\infty ,1)},$ $w_1=\chi_{(-1,\infty)}$ then the support of $w_0^{1-\theta}w_1^\theta$ is contained in $(-1,1).$  Perhaps surjectivity is valid if you restrict the spaces to the intersection of the supports of $w_0$ and $w_1.$ Concerning your first question, why do you expect that the function on RHS of $(1)$ should belong to $L^{p_0}+L^{p_1}$ ? You should expect that the mapping $z\mapsto \tilde{f}(z)$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}(L^{p_0},L^{p_1}).$ Am I right ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc oh sorry I meant to say that the RHS of (1) is in $L^{p_0} + L^{p_1}$ for a particular value of $z$.

Comment: I guess the function belongs to $L^{p_\theta}$ for ${1\over p_\theta}={1-\theta\over p_0}+{\theta\over p_1}.$ If so, the function belongs to $L^{p_0}+L^{p_1}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But how are you supposed to know a priori that it belongs to $L^{p_\theta}$? (The problem is not about the value of the exponent, even if say $p_0 = p_1 = 1$ I don't see how the hypotheses imply that $f(z) w_0^{1-z} w_1^{z}$ is integrable for $0 < z < 1$.

Comment: I am too lazy to analyze the proof in the textbook. You have declared that the tilde map is an isometry from $\mathcal{F}(L^{p_0}(w_0),L^{p_1}(w_1))$ into  $\mathcal{F}(L^{p_0},L^{p_1}).$ If so $\tilde{f}(z)\in L^{p_0}+L^{p_1}$ for any $z$ in the strip.